# openni_tracker on ubuntu 14.04 and ros indigo

Tags: openni, ros

I am running on Ubuntu 14.04 and I want to use the `openni_tracker` node of robot operating system (ROS).

My current ros-version is indigo. Unfortunately the node is only available for ROS hydro distribution.

- What should I do?
- Where to get information, if the node will be available soon?
- Are there any other solutions to track sceleton with microsoft kinect on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Do you have to use Indigo? or can you use hydro? Indigo is quite new, so it may take a while for some nodes to be upgraded. You may ask the maintainer if they will release something [here](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_tracker) you can find the emails. The other possible solution is to use nite and openni directly... I have used openni in Ubuntu 14.04, but not nite though

Answer (score 0):

You have to build from source. Just download source code from this [link](https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni_tracker), put the code in catkin workspace and run 'catkin_make' it will run on Indigo without problems.